# Connection Database SQL with RStudio

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, rstudio

I will start a new project ==> `Data visualization` by `Rstudio`. My data into a server `phpMyAdmin` `(SQL Database)`.
I will use just 4 table. So in this case I should do a link between my database and Rstudio. I found this question on `Stackoverflow` [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726926/connect-to-a-local-database-from-phpmyadmin-with-r)

I tried by this solution, I started by installed the package `mySQL`, but it return an error:
`package ‘mysql’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2`)

Knowing that I'm working on `PalantirCloud`.

Can you please give me a suggestion how can I resolve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: are you using local server / remote server?

Comment: @AshiqurRahman remore server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st grand `ALL PRIVILEGES` of remote MySQL server to a specific(database) user.

Then run these commands in Rstudio

```
install.packages("RMySQL")

library("RMySQL")

mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(),user='root',password='query',dbname='bd_test', host='192.X.X.X')
```

Where -

```
User = Remote MySQL database username
Password = Remote MySQL database user's password
dbname = Remote database name
And Host = The Remote server URL/IP address
```